# "caption"code showing in content feed Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, captions

On the main posts page (blog), the content that feeds through there is showing the [caption] code: http://www.katetremills.com/messages

I'm using this to truncate the amount of content feeding through:

```
<?php 
    echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content() , 85, "... Read More" ); 
?>
```

What's the best way to ensure the [caption] code doesn't show?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the code also that you are using to truncate the content?

Comment: sorry, although indented code above, it keeps getting stripped:  <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content() , 85, "... Read More" ); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `get_the_content()` will return the unfiltered content. Try using this:

```
<?php
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

echo wp_trim_words( $content, 85, "... Read More" ); 
?>
```

Hope this helps.